# Architecture diagram involving the flow of data between trading engine, order routing engine,quickfix and the exchange

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, algorithmic-trading, quickfixj

If I write an order routing system based on QuickfixJ, can I just start submitting my trades to an exchange? Or do I need to register myself with the exchange or get permission or something like that?

I am not able to understand how QuickfixJ, the order routing system, the actual trading engine and the exchange fits together. Any online architecture diagram would be very helpful for how these components fit together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIX is just a transmission protocol.  By itself, it's pretty dumb.  QuickFIX (any language port) is just an engine that does all the boring dirty work of managing a FIX connection.

The FIX specification includes a list of messages and fields.  In reality, you can treat these as suggestions that, in practice, no commercial FIX counterparty uses as-is.  Every counterparty I've connected to makes modifications to those messages and fields, sometimes adding entirely new messages.  **No counterparty supports *every* message and field.**

When connecting to a counterparty, **do not assume anything**.  Your counterparty should provide documentation on how they expect their interface to be used, and which messages and fields they will send and which they expect to receive from you.

- Their docs should tell you which message to send them to request market data and any special fields/options you must use.
- Their docs will tell you how to submit a trade.
- Their docs will tell you how to do anything that they support, and which messages/fields you will receive in return.

**Do not try to send any message type to your counterparty unless their docs say they support it.**

If you are writing the ORS side... then you have no docs.  If you haven't written a FIX client before, you probably shouldn't be writing a FIX server without some assistance from someone who has.  At the least, you should try to get ahold of some other systems' FIX interface docs to get an idea of how to go about it.  (Unfortunately, such firms usually only give them to client-developers.)

Comment: Thanks. SO the counterparty is the exchnage? Also, from what I understood from your answer:I implement the FIX client API while trying to write an ORS and the counterparty uses the FIX server API. What I dont understand is: WHat was the necessary to develop a new protocol, why could not we just use web services over http/soap from the ORS to the exhange to submit trades.

Comment: I'd word that as "You design and implement your ORS to expect and receive certain messages and fields, and you publish those expectations in a doc so that clients can know what messages/fields to send and expect."

Comment: I can't give you a good answer as to why they created FIX.  The trading industry is full of stupid things that exist for historical reasons, and this probably is related to them.

Comment: Thanks. Can somebody submit a trade to an exchange using web services? Or do they have to use FIX mandatorily? I ask because FIX uses Socket programming, which is an old technology.

Comment: Each exchange implements their own solutions.  You'd have to ask each particular exchange that you want to work with.  **Note:** Do not expect any two exchanges to do anything the same way.  There is remarkably little standardization in this industry.

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression that every exchange and every broker and every buy buy side and sell side firm implements FIX protocol :)

Comment: Many of them do, but even between two brokers who use FIX, the ways they use it can be very different.